# Issues with Netplan - Static IP

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, virtualbox, netplan

With the release of Ubuntu Server 20.04 I've had some weird issues concerning Netplan. I'm a student so I use Ubuntu Server as a virtual machine and I have to move a lot (which means, changing IPs all the time).

I prefer using Static IP addresses on my VM as to not change my DB connections, the same thing applies to my home.

The issue is that once I apply the correct netplan configuration the IP changes for a while but then again uses the original IP I used to configure my Server.

Right after applying Netplan configuration I have internet connection for a very short while and then it just drops the connection and gives me an error (Destination Host Unreachable)

```
ping google.com
```

the result is quite interesting, the system sends 4 packets to google.com but then shows the aforementioned message.

> (Destination Host Unreachable)

**How to resolve this issue**, since I can't really think of any solution to this "nasty" problem?

Oh and at school the server's internet connection works just fine, at home though...  already mentioned above heh :/

Also, forgot to mention:
I've got two different IP addresses in one Network card, why would this happen?

This is a welcome message Ubuntu Server shows every time I log in, there you can see the conflicting IP addresses:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-71-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue 20 Apr 17:02:42 UTC 2021

  System load:                      0.06
  Usage of /:                       13.9% of 97.93GB
  Memory usage:                     18%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        192
  Users logged in:                  1
  IPv4 address for br-22ca65208595: 172.18.0.1
  IPv4 address for br-22ca65208595: 169.254.243.117
  IPv4 address for docker0:         172.17.0.1
  IPv4 address for enp0s3:          10.0.2.133
  IPv4 address for enp0s3:          10.0.2.89
  IPv4 address for vethc48890e:     169.254.44.56
  IPv4 address for wg0:             10.6.0.1
```

**enp0s3 [1]** is the current IP address I use at school (it is a static IP but the idea is that I change it later on at home)

**enp0s3 [2]** is the IP address used initially to setup the server (it is no longer used)

Overall, the second IP address conflicts with the first one, which is why when I first apply changes in Netplan internet works for a moment but then uses the 2nd IP to send the requests to google.com.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't post screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and directly paste in in your question. Then format the text as `code` by using the { } icon above the [edit question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1332687/edit) window.

Comment: okay, didn't know that, sorry

Comment: See [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332699/netplan-create-multiple-access-point) of copying and pasting text from the terminal.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've edited my post